# Convert hebrew day-of-the-month to letter(s) in Excel

Tags: excel, hebrew

If I display a date in cell A1 using the cell format `[$-8040D] d` to show the day of the jewish month, I get a number (from 1 to 30) instead of -the way it is normally displayed- a hebrew letter.

So I want to use

```
=CHOOSE(A1,"א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","יא","יב","יג","יד","טו","טז","יז","יח","יט","כ","כא","כב","כג","כד","כה","כו","כז","כח","כט","ל")
```

But even though I *see* a number 1-30 displayed in A1, what's really there is a date serial code (something like "44181").

I have tried N(), and VALUE().

What's the *correct* way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excels stores dates numbers as per the Gregorian calendar with 1 = `1 Jan 1900` (and 1900 erroneously being deemed a leap year for competitive reasons).

So first you need to convert the date to the Jewish date (I'm assuming the Jewish Lunar calendar); extract the day of the month(with the TEXT function), and then convert that value to its Hebrew letter equivalent.

eg:

```
=CHOOSE(TEXT(A1,"[$-he-IL,8]dd"),"א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","יא","יב","יג","יד","טו","טז","יז","יח","יט","כ","כא","כב","כג","כד","כה","כו","כז","כח","כט","ל")
```

or:

```
=CHOOSE(TEXT(A1,"[$-8040D]d"),"א","ב","ג","ד","ה","ו","ז","ח","ט","י","יא","יב","יג","יד","טו","טז","יז","יח","יט","כ","כא","כב","כג","כד","כה","כו","כז","כח","כט","ל")
```

So for today which is [image: 1 Tevet]

the formula would return [image]

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" way to do it is to realize there is no problem here, no problem at all.

Yes, Excel uses a serial number dating system. However, it completely knows how to interpret it too. So you will have a serial number as the "real" content of A1, but can extract from it the day of the month value. You can do this with:

```
=TEXT(A1,"d")
```

This gets you a TEXT "6" if it is December 6. Often that fact (that it returns TEXT) can cause trouble. But only when Excel could expect you could mean either and has to guess which. In the case of the above formula it would be reasonable for it to assume you wanted it looked at as text since the function is... `TEXT()`...

But in this case, using it in the `CHOOSE()` function it can ONLY be useful if Excel treats it as a value rather than text. So it does. No need to add anything to force Excel to do so.

So you can just replace the `A1` portion of your formula with the above `TEXT()` function. Then Excel will use it properly and select the correct day of the month from the list.

And that's all you need.

Comment: This answer seems to be wrong, since it ignores the jewish *calendar* which has different months starting at different points than the gregorian calendar. "December" has no meaning or releant mapping in the jewish calendar.